# Incrementing instead of decrementing the value from input type number

Tags: javascript, html

Onclick *wordcount* input type number (increment and decrement) should display the value at *Total Cost*.

Onclick *quantity* input type number (increment and decrement) should take value from *Total Cost* and calculate display the value at *Total Cost*.

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" id="wordcount" onchange="calTotal();" name="wordcount" value="" min="1" max="100000000000" id="wordcount" >

<input class="form-control" type="number"  id="quantity"  onchange="calTotal();" name="quantity" value="" min="1" max="100000000000">
```

Display the results here:

```
<input type="number"  readonly="readonly" min="1n" name="total" id="running-summary-total" value="0.00">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAFNZ.png)

Javascript to do calculations:

```
<script>
function calTotal(){
var z = document.getElementById("wordcount").value;

    console.log(z)
   if (document.getElementById("wordcount").value) {
     var wc = z * 0.098;
   document.getElementById("running-summary-total").value =  +wc;
    }
   if (document.getElementById("quantity").value) {
    var r = document.getElementById("running-summary-total").value 
     var wc = r * 2;
   document.getElementById("running-summary-total").value =  +wc;
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]
I have no issue with the `wordcount` function but I have 
issue with quantity when I decrement the value in `document.getElementById("quantity").value` it's incrementing it instead of decrementing it by 2.

Comment: but shouldnt you just do `var wc = r - 2;` then?

Comment: where should i place this ```var wc = r - 2;```?

Comment: inside the `getElementById("quantity").value` if

Comment: Kindly refer to the image above, so as you understand my issue

Comment: well at the moment it is incrementing by 2 because you set `var wc = r * 2;` this in your code. but you would like the value of `E` to replace the 2 in that code? and what calculation should it do? is it grabbing `D` and dividing it by `E` or decreasing by `E`?

Comment: Onchange the value in **E** should Grab the value in **C** and divide by 2 on decrease as well as Grabbing  the value in **C** and multiply by 2 on increase and display the final result in **C**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the comments and provided explaination. i think this is what you are looking for:

```js
function calTotal(){
 let wordcount = $("#wordcount").val();//get wordcount value
  let quantity = $("#quantity").val();//get quantity value
 if(wordcount){//if wordcount has value
  var wc = wordcount * 0.098;
    $("#running-summary-total").val(wc);
 }
  if(quantity && quantity < 0){//if quantity has value and its smaller then 0 (negative value)
   let oldtotal = $("#running-summary-total").val();//getting the old total value
    let calc = Math.abs(quantity) * 2;//added Math.abs to turn negative number into positive, and mulitply by 2
    let newtotal = oldtotal / calc;// here we divide the old total by the quatity times 2
    $("#running-summary-total").val(newtotal);
  }
  if(quantity && quantity > 0){//if quantity has value and its bigger then 0 (positive value)
   let oldtotal = $("#running-summary-total").val();//getting the old total value
    let calc = quantity * 2;//here we multiply quantity by 2
    let newtotal = oldtotal * calc;// here we multiply the old total by the quantity times 2
    $("#running-summary-total").val(newtotal);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input class="form-control" type="number" id="wordcount" onchange="calTotal();" name="wordcount" value="" min="1" max="100000000000">

   <input class="form-control" type="number"  id="quantity"  onchange="calTotal();" name="quantity" value="" min="" max="100000000000">
   
   <input type="number"  readonly="readonly" min="1n" name="total" id="running-summary-total" value="0.00">
```

i've rewritten it into jquery code(my plain javascript isn't very good)

**edit** added support for negative values and multiply for positive values(was dividing at first).

Comment: Onclick on *quantity* up arrow its divide it instead of multiply @ramon-de-vries

Comment: Thank you soo much, you really help! i have clicked thank you button

Comment: @ Ramon de Vries, i am grateful for your help,one more help, would there be any way the defined value in *C* be passed to then increment *D* and so on. In other words when  you increment or decrement *D*  it will start incrementing from the old value in *C*

Answer (score 1):

Your code is currently taking in the value of total and multiplying them by 2 
without considering the value of the quantity input or the value of wordcount.

```
function calTotal(){
  var wordCount = document.getElementById("wordcount").value;
  let quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

  document.getElementById("running-summary-total").value =  wordCount * quantity

}
```

Comment: this code is still multiplying, wich is not what OP asked

Comment: I have updated with a simplified version of what I understand OP is looking for,

Comment: I need the total cost ```C``` be divided by 2 when onchange the value in quantity ```E```  and also the value from total cost ```C```  be multiplied by 2 when onchange the value in quantity ```E```

Comment: The one you provided above does not factor in total cost ```C```

Comment: You can then multiply that last amount by a `costPerWord` variable and you will have your required value